# Docker Compose - Not picking up the dump file in the init command?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have following syntax in windows based docker enr. however when i run the

```
docker-compose up
```

it loads the container however don't load the dump file inside the dump file location given as the entry-point to the mysql process.

any ideas ? below is the my docker-compose.yml file.

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes_from:
        - data
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: yxxxxr
        MYSQL_DATABASE: career_xxx
        MYSQL_USER: career_xxx
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: Ixxx8; 

data:
    image: mysql:latest
    #image: mysql:5.6
    #image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
        - ./.config/etc/mysql/dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    command: "true"
```

Comment: Is `dump` a file or a folder? I think only `sql` extensions will be loaded.

Comment: yes, dump is a folder, and sql files are there, not getting loaded for somereason and there is no error.

Comment: Try use an absolute path

Comment: doesnt work, you can try this yourself see if this working isnt it ? dosnt work for me

Comment: Tried this on my machine and it works. Make sure you delete containers from previous `docker-compose up` first. Somehow if you have run it before, even though docker-compose says it is recreating the containers, it will not run the sql file. But when you start fresh it works.

Comment: Also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347845/mysql-container-failing-to-run-initialisation-scripts-in-docker-compose It suggests to run `docker-compose rm -vf` to remove old volumes.

Comment: yes that did the trick, i you like to add that as the answer here

Comment: Please clarify which comment worked and I'll add as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: docker-compose rm -vf to remove old volumes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @warmoverflow pointed out its seems to be bug in the docker, you have to remove all the volumes out and then it will work.

```
//to remove all volumes (do this after every docker-composer up)
$ docker-compose rm -vf
```