# tomcat + mysql + war using docker-compose.yml

Tags: mysql, docker, tomcat, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose.yml to build my enviroment.

docker-compose.yml

```
  version: '3'

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.5
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: my-test-app
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        volumes:
          - ./docker/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        ports:
           - "3306:3306"

      tomcat:
        image: tomcat:8.5.35
        container_name: tomcat
        volumes:
          - ./docker/myapp.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
```

My folder structore

```
my-env            
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docker
    ├── myapp.war
    ├── db
         ├── DB_INIT.SQL
```

DB_INIT.SQL

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  EMPLOYEE_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
  DOB DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  GENDER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  MOBILE VARCHAR(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4;


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME, DOB, GENDER, MOBILE, EMAIL) VALUES ("Aung Ko Tint", '1986-12-02', 'MALE', '09458682152', 'aungko@demo.com');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME, DOB, GENDER, MOBILE, EMAIL) VALUES ("Hein Thu", '1990-10-25', 'MALE', '0942562871', 'mthk@demo.com');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME, DOB, GENDER, MOBILE, EMAIL) VALUES ("Arr Yone", '1991-12-15', 'MALE', '0942255023', 'hwyk@demo.com');
```

After running this commend `docker-compose up`,

My docker-machine ip is `192.168.99.100`.
I can access `http://192.168.99.100:8080` of tomcat, but I cannot acess my app `http://192.168.99.100:8080/myapp`. It was `404`.

I can access `docker's mysql` from my host by using `MySQL Work Branch`.
In `MySQL Work Branch`, I see `my-test-app` database. but There is no `EMPLOYEE` table.

Tomcat & Mysql are successfuly install. But my `war` and `init sql script` are not OK.
Is there any missing config in my `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: When and how do you run the init sql script?

Comment: @Hannes
`volumes:
          - ./docker/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`
It is not OK?

Comment: Yes, it should work, the sql file should be executed automatically. I tried to get it to work in my test environment but without luck. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

***For the Database:***

Maybe you run in the same problem as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348572/8221303

**1.** At first run this to delete the current containers:

```
docker-compose rm -vf
```

**2.** Remove database name from compose file.

**3.** Modify your database creation file like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE `my-test-app`;
USE my-test-app;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  EMPLOYEE_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
  DOB DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  GENDER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  MOBILE VARCHAR(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4;


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME, DOB, GENDER, MOBILE, EMAIL) VALUES ("Zaw Than Oo", '1986-12-02', 'MALE', '09420000773', 'zawthanoo@cycdemo.com');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME, DOB, GENDER, MOBILE, EMAIL) VALUES ("Myo Thiha Kyaw", '1990-10-25', 'MALE', '0942568971', 'mthk@cycdemo.com');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME, DOB, GENDER, MOBILE, EMAIL) VALUES ("Htet Wai Yan Kyaw", '1991-12-15', 'MALE', '0942025023', 'hwyk@cycdemo.com');
```

**4.** Run Docker-Compose again. When the containers are starting you should see something like this in the stdout:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/DB_INIT.sql
```

***For the Tomcat:***

Maybe your application does not run because of the DB problem. But if not you can try the following:

At first check if the WAR file is deployed correctly. Connect to the container bash via:

```
docker exec -it tomcat bash
```

Check if there is the war file with the deployed one in the webapps directory:

```
 /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```