# Docker-compose initialize DB

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'

services:        
  db:
      image: mysql:latest
      container_name: mysql
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
      volumes:
        - ./docker/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
```

and a MySQL script to initialize the DB.

```
CREATE DATABASE `aaa`;
USE `aaa`;


CREATE TABLE `building` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cap` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `province` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `req_amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Actually Docker ignore the file INIT_DB.SQL as stated:

```
mysql | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/DB_INIT.SQL
```

I want to initialize the DB with that file. I've also tried that: [tomcat + mysql + war using docker-compose.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701629/tomcat-mysql-war-using-docker-compose-yml).

Where's the mistake?

Comment: `docker-entrypoint.sh` recognizes `*.sh`, `*.sql` and `*.sql.gz` files as init files. `*.SQL` is not among them (Linux is case-sensitive), so it is ignored.

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/68f5102a73d8df4d739c20c581518850350794f6/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L52

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. I renamed it but it still give the same error :(

Comment: you need to delete the containers and images and recreate them

Comment: I did it, i've used ```docker-compose rm -vf```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

    environment:
      TZ: "America/Halifax"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: formulary

    volumes:
    - ./mysql-init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql-init.sql
    - ./mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

The only difference between what you put and what I put is that I put the source file/target file (not just the directories). As well, are you sure ./docker/db contains your file?

Comment: my ./docker/db/INIT_DB.sql exists, adding the complete path to INIT_DB.sql it says: ```mysql | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/INIT_DB.sql
mysql | ERROR: Can't initialize batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device. ```

Comment: Initializing a container results in ERROR: Can't initialize batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device. when a mounted file is missing from the host due to docker's behavior to create an empty directory for any missing mounted file. -> it sounds like you have a typo in your filename, or it's not readable. Or if you ran this docker-compose file before the sql file existed and created an empty dir of that name.

Answer (score 0):

got the same errror with the comments below the first answer (..is a directory). what actually worked for me;

```
postgres:
  volumes:
    - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```